# Adding few images in Java JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, awt

I'm making 2D game. I have background and character images. Both of them are .gif files. What layout or something do I need to use to set background behind the character? I tried some ways but either they're in a row or nothing happens.

I am adding pictures like that:

```
URL url = Main.class.getResource("images/main.gif");
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(url);
JLabel background = new JLabel(imageIcon);
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and what it produced.

Comment: Just adding images on panel with different variants of layouts. Sometimes there was frame with size of character image, sometimes images were in a row

Comment: Do some research into 2D Graphics and custom painting in Swing

Answer (score 0):

Code for Background :

1. first of all copy your background image and paste in src of code
2. than set layout to borderlayout like this:

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

3. now add this code:

setContentPane(new JLabel new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image.jpg"))));

Note: add your image name here "image.jpg"

4. now set layout to flow layout like this

setLayout(new FlowLayout());

5. and write your code here

Comment: Am I need to change layout on frame few times?

Comment: Beware, using a JLabel to show the background, won't calculate the preferred size the same way as other components and will only include the text and icon properties. A better solution, in this case, would be to custom paint be entire content

Comment: Yeah you are right. I'll keep this in mind and thanks for the advice.